# How to determine if a user joined/switched/left a voice channel?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm using Discord.Net and observe several voice channels. If these voice channels have a muted state, set by the bot (not via permissions), users in that voice channel should be muted too.

Simply removing the speak permission from a voice channel won't affect people instantly as you can see here

https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360052856033-Directly-affect-people-in-channels-on-permission-changes

If they leave it they should get unmuted.

So this one is holding all the required information

```
public sealed class ObservedVoiceChannel
{
    public ulong VoiceChannelId { get; set; }
    public bool IsMuted { get; set; }
    // ... other information go here ...
}
```

and I have a service holding all the observed voice channels

```
public sealed class ObservedVoiceChannelsCache : Dictionary<ulong, ObservedVoiceChannel>
{
}
```

Since there only is a `UserVoiceStateUpdated` event I came up with the following code.

After some tests I think this code works fine for me. Although I know the if statements can be improved in terms of readability with "or" operators I will do it after fixing the last problem.

When leaving an observed muted voice channel, see the comment

> // user left observed muted voice channel

the user won't get unmuted by the bot. Sometimes, when joining and leaving fast enough the handler throws an exception

> The server responded with error 400: BadRequest

> at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
> at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestQueue.SendAsync(RestRequest request)    at
> Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendInternalAsync(String method,
> String endpoint, RestRequest request)    at
> Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendJsonAsync(String method, String
> endpoint, Object payload, BucketId bucketId, ClientBucketType
> clientBucket, RequestOptions options)    at
> Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.ModifyGuildMemberAsync(UInt64
> guildId, UInt64 userId, ModifyGuildMemberParams args, RequestOptions
> options)    at Discord.Rest.UserHelper.ModifyAsync(IGuildUser user,
> BaseDiscordClient client, Action`1 func, RequestOptions options)    at
> ...OnUserVoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState
> oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState) in
> /.../UserVoiceStateUpdatedEventHandler.cs:line 52

This is the code I'm currently using

```
public sealed class UserVoiceStateUpdatedEventHandler
{
    private readonly ObservedVoiceChannelsCache _observedVoiceChannelsCache;
    
    public UserVoiceStateUpdatedEventHandler(ObservedVoiceChannelsCache observedVoiceChannelsCache)
    {
        _observedVoiceChannelsCache = observedVoiceChannelsCache;
    }
    
    public async Task OnUserVoiceStateUpdated(
        SocketUser socketUser, 
        SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState,
        SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    {
        if (socketUser is SocketGuildUser socketGuildUser)
        {
            bool userIsMuted = socketGuildUser.VoiceState?.IsMuted == true;
            bool userIsNotOffline = socketGuildUser.Status != UserStatus.Offline;
            
            // user left observed muted voice channel
            if (oldSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel != null && 
                newSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel == null &&
                _observedVoiceChannelsCache.TryGetValue(oldSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel.Id, out ObservedVoiceChannel observedLeftVoiceChannel) &&
                observedLeftVoiceChannel.IsMuted &&
                userIsMuted &&
                userIsNotOffline
                )
            {
                await SetUserMuteState(socketGuildUser, false);
            }
            // user joined observed muted voice channel
            else if (oldSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel == null && 
                     newSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel != null &&
                     _observedVoiceChannelsCache.TryGetValue(newSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel.Id, out ObservedVoiceChannel observedJoinedVoiceChannel) &&
                     observedJoinedVoiceChannel.IsMuted &&
                     !userIsMuted &&
                     userIsNotOffline)
            {
                await SetUserMuteState(socketGuildUser, true);
            }
            // user changed voice channels
            else if (oldSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel != null && 
                     newSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel != null &&
                     userIsNotOffline)
            {
                bool oldVoiceChannelObserved = _observedVoiceChannelsCache.TryGetValue(
                    oldSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel.Id, out ObservedVoiceChannel oldObservedVoiceChannel);
                
                bool newVoiceChannelObserved = _observedVoiceChannelsCache.TryGetValue(
                    newSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel.Id, out ObservedVoiceChannel newObservedVoiceChannel);

                // user moved from observed muted voice channel to unobserved voice channel
                if (oldVoiceChannelObserved && 
                    !newVoiceChannelObserved &&
                    oldObservedVoiceChannel.IsMuted &&
                    userIsMuted)
                {
                    await SetUserMuteState(socketGuildUser, false);
                }
                // user moved from unobserved voice channel to observed muted voice channel
                else if (!oldVoiceChannelObserved && 
                         newVoiceChannelObserved &&
                         newObservedVoiceChannel.IsMuted &&
                         !userIsMuted)
                {
                    await SetUserMuteState(socketGuildUser, true);
                }
                // both voice channels are observed
                else if (oldVoiceChannelObserved && newVoiceChannelObserved)
                {
                    // user moved from muted to unmuted voice channel
                    if (oldObservedVoiceChannel.IsMuted && 
                        !newObservedVoiceChannel.IsMuted &&
                        userIsMuted)
                    {
                        await SetUserMuteState(socketGuildUser, false);
                    }
                    // user moved from unmuted to muted voice channel
                    else if (!oldObservedVoiceChannel.IsMuted && 
                             newObservedVoiceChannel.IsMuted && 
                             !userIsMuted)
                    {
                        await SetUserMuteState(socketGuildUser, true);
                    }
                    // user moved from muted to muted voice channel
                    else if (oldObservedVoiceChannel.IsMuted && 
                             newObservedVoiceChannel.IsMuted && 
                             !userIsMuted)
                    {
                        await SetUserMuteState(socketGuildUser, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Task SetUserMuteState(SocketGuildUser socketGuildUser, bool muteUser)
        => socketGuildUser.ModifyAsync(guildUserProperties => guildUserProperties.Mute = muteUser);
}
```

and I would like to know how to unmute users which left the observed muted voice channel.

I found out that this line here

```
bool userIsMuted = socketGuildUser.VoiceState?.IsMuted == true;
```

returns false after leaving the voice channel because the voice state is null. So it seems there is no way to check if the user would be muted when joining again.

Answer (score 0):

The way you determine whether someone is joining, moving, or leaving voice channels is by looking at the `SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState` and `SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState` parameters' **VoiceChannel** properties respectively. (`oldSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel` -> `newSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel` for the examples below):

- Entering a new voice channel from not being connected (null -> channel A)
- Moving between voice channels (channel A -> channel B)
- Disconnecting from a voice channel (channel B -> null)

To mute someone who joins a voice channel and then to unmute them once they disconnect, you would write the following:

```cs
public async Task LogUserVoiceStateUpdatedAsync(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState curVoiceState,
    SocketVoiceState nextVoiceState)
{
    if (user is not SocketGuildUser guildUser)
    {
        // They aren't a guild user, so we can't do anything to them.
        return;
    }
    
    // Note, you should make a method for the two switches below as in 
    // reality you're only changing one true/false flag depending on 
    // the voice states.
    
    // The user is leaving the voice channel.
    if (curVoiceState.VoiceChannel != null && nextVoiceState.VoiceChannel == null)
    {
        // Unmute the user.
        try
        {
            // Surround in try-catch in the event we lack permissions.
            await guildUser.ModifyAsync(x => x.Mute = false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Will ALWAYS throw 400 bad request. I don't exactly know why, 
            // but it has to do with the modification being done after the user leaves the voice channel.
            
            // The warning can be safely be ignored.
            // _logger.LogWarning(e, $"Failed to unmute user in guild {guildUser.Guild.Id}.");
        }
    }
    else if (curVoiceState.VoiceChannel == null && nextVoiceState.VoiceChannel != null)
    {
        // Mute the user.
        try
        {
            // Surround in try-catch in the event we lack permissions.
            await guildUser.ModifyAsync(x => x.Mute = true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(e, $"Failed to mute user in guild {guildUser.Guild.Id}.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unmuting a leaving user always throws a 400? If that's the case then the OP's code should be fine I think ...

Comment: @StageCodes thanks for your reply but what if a user switches a voice channel? then `curVoiceState.VoiceChannel` won't be null. And if that's the case, how does your code differ from mine =?

Comment: @Question3r Yes, you are correct. Our code differs in that yours references a cache, mine doesn't. Your code is making the issue more complicated than it needs to be, my code is easier to read and safely mutes the user. With your code, if you mute the user as-is and don't have permissions to do so in a server, you will encounter an unhandled exception and I believe the program would crash.

Comment: @StageCodes yes, well the problem is that when a user leaves a voice channel I can't unmute him anymore. I tried your code and mine too, both are struggling

Comment: In my testing I was unmuted as soon as I disconnected from the voice channel and was muted again when I rejoined.

Comment: Why I wasn't marked as the accepted answer for the bounty?